# model.predict_classes for Non-sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to predict_classes for vgg16 network. When I compile `custom_vgg_model.predict_classes()` 
then I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'.

In sequential model, it working fine when I use `model.predict_classes(x)` but How to predict classes for vgg16?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer for your question? I have the same issue..